# Iterating through NSSet

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following task:
I'm given an NSSet of objects each of which has ID_, FB_USER_ID and Email fields
Please help me, how to quickly create 3 NSArrarys that contain those fields(NSArray with ID_s, NSArray with FB_USER_IDs and an array with emails)?

Comment: hey guyz, if you downvoting my question you please tell me why, at least ??!

Comment: "each of which has ID_, FB_USER_ID and Email fields" <- what kind of fields? Are they objects and these are @properties? Or NSDictionaries with these keys?

Comment: `NSEnumerator`: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSArray *id_s = [[theSet valueForKey:@"ID_"] allObjects];
NSArray *fb_user_ids = [[theSet valueForKey:@"FB_USER_ID"] allObjects];
NSArray *emails = [[theSet valueForKey:@"Email"] allObjects];
```

That should work regardless if your set contains dictionaries or objects with defined properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for: [[theSet valueForKey:@"ID_"] allObjects];